# why i can't use all my sd card space on Apps?

Tags: applications, external-sd, sd-card, storage, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I have a Xperia E1 with 2Gb of internal memory. I had to buy an 8GB SD card to use good apps! The problem is that I can only use 2Gb of my SD card on apps! When I open the storage it say it has 6.90Gb free, but when I open from Apps settings and check on SD card it say 505Gb free.

http://s21.postimg.org/mtcj0r1s7/image.jpg

http://s21.postimg.org/ubvo9dt53/e1872b176fa9f6e9b46b2ef59e107b6d6f88ba4bb3ca610c.jpg

Comment: `SD card it say 505Gb free.` I don't even have a Hard drive of this much space! http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/103959/edit

Answer (score 0):

It is because since older versions of android(i don't remember which exactly) its not possible to install or move apps to **SD CARD without root**.

All apps will be installed in **internal memory by default** however if you do root you can move them to your SD Card using apps(there are many) and at same time you will be able to delete **useless pre-installed apps** that is using your internal memory space.

Also i just noticed that u have **370MB** of cache data, that data is near useless, since its just used to make things load faster but eventually it start to use too much space on your drive so you can safely delete the cache of all your apps, you can use apps for that...I use Cache Cleaner

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "since older versions of android," but it hasn't been **that** long. KitKat was the first version to make the SD card read-only (excluding some system-provided apps).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Sony's Xperia E1 specifications page](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-e1/specifications), you're running Android 4.4, KitKat. As mentioned in numerous SE articles, KitKat does not allow the SD card to be used for app storage, including transferring apps to it. Sony's page does say you can add it, but unless they hacked KitKat, it won't work.

Comment: but i can transfer them to Sd card ! but they allow me to use only 2Gb of it on apps ! while it's 8Gb sd card

Comment: That's not standard for KitKat. Normally the SD card is replaced by a separate flash area internally. Sony must be doing something strange.